# How do I topologically sort a rooted tree from the "parentOf" relation?

Tags: python-3.x, tree, topological-sort

I have a N-node rooted tree whose nodes are labeled 0 through N-1.  I am given the *parentOf* relation, that is, for each node `i`, `parentOf[i]` is the single node `j` such that `j` is the parent of `i`.  I would like to sort the nodes of the tree from bottom to top.  I've seen implementations of *topological sort*, but they are based on the inverse relation *childrenOf*.  How do I implement the sort using the *parentOf* relation without explicitly inverting the relation?

Suppose that for the following tree:

```
                          0
                         / \
                        /   \
                       2     1
                            / \
                           /   \
                          3     4
```

We are given the `parentOf` array `[-1,0,0,1,1]`, where the `-1` indicates that node 0 has no parent.  In that case we want to construct the topologically-sorted node list:  `[3,4,2,1,0]`, that is, nodes always appear before their parents.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Can you show an example tree and what should be the result?